# Can someone explain to me this code?

Tags: mysql

I saw this code and I waned to ask you guys if you can explain to me how this code works thanks.

```
select SUM(IF(encodedRestDay & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(selected_date)-1)) > 0, 1, NULL)) as numberOfRestDay from (
    select *, if ( encodedRestDay & (1 << (DAYOFWEEK(selected_date)-1)) > 0,
    'restDay', 'workDay'
    ) as dayStatus, dayName(selected_date) as `dayName` from (
        select *,  (sat << 6 | fri << 5 | thu << 4 | wed << 3 | tue << 2 | mon << 1 | sun) as encodedRestDay from (
            select adddate('2014-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as selected_date,
                sat, fri, thu, wed, tue, mon, sun
            from 
                    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4,
            restday
            where id = 6
            ) v

            where selected_date between '2014-02' and '2014-04'
        )a
    )b
```

Comment: Was the person wrote possibly being paid but the number of `select` statements?

Comment: I bet the query is attempting to pivot date values over days of the week of using a sub query and finally aggregating the results.

Comment: I would ask the person who coded it what the intention of the query is (or read the comments... there are comments right?.. oh), then rewrite it. The fact you are asking "what does it do" means it's a bad query, let alone the obvious performance issues this would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is doing complex date arithmetic in order to count the number of "rest" days between two dates.  (This is presumably the number of non-working days.)  The data structure is flexible enough to handle different "cultures" of working days.

This subquery:

```
        select adddate('2014-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as selected_date,
            sat, fri, thu, wed, tue, mon, sun
        from 
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4,
        restday
        where id = 6
```

is creating a calendar of days starting from 2014-01-01 for the next 10,000 days.  It is doing this for every row in `restday` subject to `id = 6`.  Without the layout of the table, it is hard to understand what this means, or what the day of the week columns really mean.  I speculate that they tell you whether a day is a working day or rest day for a particular culture.

The next level:

```
    select *,  (sat << 6 | fri << 5 | thu << 4 | wed << 3 | tue << 2 | mon << 1 | sun) as encodedRestDay
    from (
```

is doing some bit shifting.  That way, something like `1001011` represents the days Saturday, Wednesday, Monday, and Sunday.

The outermost query is then doing some sort of comparison to get "rest" days (if I understand correctly).

This is the gist of the query.  I don't fully understand what `restday` is doing; I suspect that it has different workday patterns for different cultures or shifts.